# How can I stop windows explorer differentiate version information when I group files by type

Tags: windows-7, file-organization

In windows 7, when I group files by type, it automatically group files by different versions. For example. Word 97-2003 files and Word 2010 files are grouped in two groups. How can I make windows explorer group all Word files in one group regardless of versions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Word 97-2003 and Word 2010 files have the .DOC and .DOCX extensions respectively by default. Their file type descriptions are also different, so naturally if you sort according to *Type* in Windows Explorer they'll be grouped separately.

A simple solution would be to sort according to *Name* or any other common characteristic.

If you want to sort by *Type* and still have them grouped together, you can try editing the description via *regedit* (registry editor).

The description for Word 2010 .DOCX files is "Microsoft Word Document" (see `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.12`). Leave that be.

The description for Word 97-2003 .DOC files is "Microsoft Word 97 - 2003 Document", so you can go change the **(Default)** value at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8` to be the same as that for .DOCX files.

Reboot and check if both file types now have the same description and are sorted together in Explorer.

**Note:** This has not been tested by me so do it at your own risk and do not complain if Word stops functioning properly, or resets the registry entries on its own.